# How to find the smallest version number in an array of browser–version pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m looking for alternative solutions for returning specific items from an array.

```
[
  ["chrome", "72"],
  ["chrome", "71"],
  ["chrome", "70"],
  ["edge", "18"],
  ["edge", "17"]
]
```

How would I return the oldest version of each browser, e.g. `[ [ "chrome", "70" ], [ "edge", "17" ] ]`?

I currently have a filter for `chrome` and a filter for `edge`, etc. But I wonder if there’s a cleaner way of achieving the same result.

Comment: Is this static JavaScript array or you are deriving it dynamically ?

Comment: one-liner: `result = new Map(versions.sort((x, y) => x[1] - y[1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `min`

```js
const data = 
  [ ["chrome", "72"]
  , ["chrome", "71"]
  , ["chrome", "70"]
  , ["edge", "18"]
  , ["edge", "17"]
  ]

const result = 
  data.reduce
    ( (acc, [ browser, version ]) =>
        ({ ...acc, [browser]: Math.min(version, acc[browser] || Infinity) })
    , {}
    )
    
console.log(result)
// { "chrome": 70
// , "edge": 17
// }

console.log(Object.entries(result))
// [ [ "chrome", 70 ]
// , [ "edge", 17 ]
// ]
```

If you want the latest version, use `max` instead -

```
const result = 
  data.reduce
    ( (acc, [ browser, version ]) =>
        ({ ...acc, [browser]: Math.max(version, acc[browser] || 0) })
    , {}
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

You’ll need to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) this array into an object, where each key is the name of the browser and the values are the oldest version. A simple `if` statement checking which version is older is more than enough. Use [destructuring for `[browser, version]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make things simpler:

```
const browsers = [
  ["chrome", "72"],
  ["chrome", "71"],
  ["chrome", "70"],
  ["edge", "18"],
  ["edge", "17"]
];

browsers.reduce((oldest, [browser, version]) => {
  if(!oldest.hasOwnProperty(browser) || Number(oldest[browser]) > Number(version)){
    oldest[browser] = version;
  }

  return oldest;
}, {});
```

At this point, you get this structure: `{chrome: "70", edge: "17"}`. This can be passed to [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or its [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill) to create the desired array:

```
Object.entries({chrome: "70", edge: "17"});
// => [ [ "chrome", "70" ], [ "edge", "17" ] ]
```

---

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979426/javascript-array-assistance-for-filtering-strings/55979499#comment98608862_55979446) you’ve mentioned that your input array will always be sorted from highest to lowest. In that case, you may use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) or its polyfill and achieve your result in a single line:

```
Object.entries(Object.fromEntries(browsers));
// => [ [ "chrome", "70" ], [ "edge", "17" ] ]
```

`fromEntries` iterates through the input array top to bottom and assigns each key–value pair to an object. Entries with duplicate keys will be overwritten, and since the desired versions are at the bottom, that’s exactly what you want.

If the desired entries were at the bottom, you may use something like `Object.entries(Object.fromEntries(browsers.reverse()))`. Otherwise, this line gives you the newest versions.